# Cancelling an attendee's meeting invite without notification in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2016, exchange-2016

I have a really nasty suspicion that my boss sneaked in behind me and cancelled an important meeting on my Outlook 2016 calendar which I had accepted and was supposed to be attending alongside him. My boss was the owner of the calendar invite originally. He somehow made the meeting disappear on my calendar and made me look a fool in front of the business by not attending. He hates my guts and doesn't want me to outperform him during meeting with business stakeholders.

The above being told, does anyone here know how this is possible in Outlook 2016? Making a meeting disappear off someone's calendar without sending a cancellation notice. Is this a super admin account in Microsoft Exchange he is using to sneak in on my calendar, email and other Outlook 2016 assets?

Answers are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Did you share your calendar with your boss? If you are just an attendee to an meeting, you or the one who have edit permission on your calendar can easily 'delete' the meeting in your calendar via selecting the meeting and pressing Delete. However, this doesn't actually remove you from the attendee list, this just removes the copy of the meeting from your calendar view. If the meeting organizer then sends an update to the meeting, the meeting will show up again in your Calendar.

If you are the organizer of the meeting, it's also possible to delete the meeting without notifying other attendees. You just need to put your Outlook to offline mode, send the cancellation so the cancellation shows up in your Outbox. Go to Outbox and delete the cancellation message. In this way, no attendees will receive any notifications.